# PHP Using variable as index name of an json.parse array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following json as response from http request :-

```
{
    "advice_cat": [
        {
            "id": 22,
            "title": "Motivation",
            "type": "advice_cat",
            "description": "test",

            }
        },
        {
            "id": 29,
            "title": "Test",
            "type": "advice_cat",
            "description": "",
            }
        }
    ],
```

After decoding the json to an php array:

```
$cat = json_decode($response);
```

I am able to access any keys/value using :-

```
$cat->advice_cat->title          Output:  Motivation
```

My question is, how can i use a variable as index name, for example

```
$cat->$variable->title
```

Comment: Problem is elsewhere. Why you need this approach?

Comment: I find it hard to believe you're able to read that value since `advice_cat` is an array, so you'd be missing `[0]` in there before `title`. Anyways, that should work if `$variable` is `advice_cat`.

Comment: I just noticed, that's not valid JSON.

Comment: @FirstOne : last comma `,` indicates that he just shared half of json, may be he using valid json

Comment: @RishiRaut I can understand that, but what about closing `}` before `]`? Ctrl+F to highlight shows 3 `{` and 4 `}`. It would be ok it that was the opposite, as a result of removing the end of the json, but it's not.

Comment: This should work: [https://eval.in/907493](https://eval.in/907493).

Answer (score -1):

As you are saying you are able to get value by this code

```
$cat->advice_cat->title          Output:  Motivation
```

I think you want like this, I Assume you are using any loop to display value

```
$variable = 'advice_cat';
$cat->{$variable}->title
```

Comment: Close. Missing array level `$cat->{$variable}[0]->title`, as [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485613/php-using-variable-as-index-name-of-an-json-parse-array#comment81926203_47485613)

Comment: @FirstOne : what about this statement  `I am able to access any keys/value using` in this line  `$cat->advice_cat->title`

Comment: That's when our personal filter comes in. You don't have to believe everything you listen / read. [https://eval.in/907494](https://eval.in/907494). You'll get used to it, in SO.

Comment: @FirstOne : you are right he needs to describe more about. Otherwise this example works : https://eval.in/907506